# Ansible loop over nested and string loop

Tags: list, ansible, nested

My goal is to have a task that runs in a loop over multiple objects in a list, one of those objects is a list itself.
When i separate the list from the normal vars it works as expected, to save code i want to do them both in the same task.

The following playbook does not output my expected result, it prints all the objects of the list instead of iterating over them, how can i iterate over them essentially as a nested list?
Ty very much :)

I have the following playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    test_var:
      - name: "ben"
      - name: "ben_test"
  tasks:
    - name: test print
      shell: "echo {{ item }}"
      loop:
        - "ben_str"
        - "ben_second_str"
        - "{{ test_var }}"
```

Also tried to have in the shell some `if` conditionals without success, would love to know so i can save some code instead of double printing.

In my case it's a more complex code, just for simplicity reasons using echo and shell :)
Ty for the help.

Comment: ["it's not working"](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) is not an accurate description of your problem. Please read [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section, then [edit] your question to add more details. In this case we need to know/view the exact result you get and the one you expect instead. Meanwhile, reading between the lines, I suspect that replacing `loop:` with `with_items:` (which will automagically apply the `flatten` filter on the given list for the loop) might do what you wish.

Comment: @Zeitounator
Sorry, my bad with typing it, i meant it's not printing the each item like i wanted.
Is there a way of doing it without with_items due to the migration from with_x to loop?
Tried applying some flatten filters with no success.

Comment: from the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html): `We have not deprecated the use of with_<lookup> - that syntax will still be valid for the foreseeable future.` Meanwhile, I already gave you a hint in my first comment to do that keeping `loop:` => (shortcut notation because of comment...) `loop: "{{ (['ben_str', 'ben_second_str'] + test_var) | flatten }}"`

Comment: @Zeitounator

also how can i just print the value of name instead of the key: value?
I essentially only want to print "ben" and "ben_test" from the test_var dictionary list.

Comment: ansible has the `debug` module (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html), this can help you to print the values of a variable; in your case you're echoing (sending to the console of the hosts) the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I get what you are trying to do exactly but I suspect both examples below should achieve what you expect. Meanwhile, I'd like to emphasize your data structure is absolutely not ideal (i.e. mix of string and list within the same list, mix of strings and objects in the same result flattened list....).

Note: the list of options below is not exhaustive

Option 1:

```yaml
     - name: test print
       debug:
         var: item
       vars:
         my_list:
           - "ben_str"
           - "ben_second_str"
           - "{{ test_var | map(attribute='name') }}"
       loop: "{{ my_list | flatten }}"
```

Option 2:

```yaml
    - name: test print
      debug:
        var: item
      with_items:
        - "ben_str"
        - "ben_second_str"
        - "{{ test_var | map(attribute='name') }}"
```

Option 3:

```yaml
    - name: test print
      debug:
        var: item
      vars:
        my_other_list:
          - "ben_str"
          - "ben_second_str"
      loop: "{{ my_other_list + test_var | map(attribute='name') }}"
```

which all give inserted in your above original play containing the `test_var` definition:

```
TASK [test print] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=ben_str) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "ben_str"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=ben_second_str) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "ben_second_str"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=ben) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "ben"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=ben_test) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "ben_test"
}
```

Comment: When i do the same thing my result for the `"{{ test_var  | map(attribute='name') }}"` list is:
`"item": "<generator object do_map at xxx>"`
Is this intentional? i wrote `test_var` variable  the same as i have in the original post.
regarding the data structure, it's due to dynamically finding files and wanting to delete them at the same time of having known file names.

Comment: Added `| list` after the `| map(attribute='name')` and worked for me, can you edit answer so i can approve? ty :)

Comment: @benshalev can you upgrade your ansible version to one that is still supported and maintained (i.e. anything equal or superior to  2.11) so that I don't have to edit the answer? => `pip install --upgrade ansible`. Needing the `list` filter means you are using ansitble 2.9 (or lower...) which is end-of-life for over 2 years now. If you feel like an edit is still needed, you are able to edit any question or answer like anybody else here.

Comment: Okay, approved the answer, ty very much :)